# Looking to define a variable of length 50K in a Library in Dev Ops

Tags: azure-devops

I need to define variable of size 50K chars in dev ops project library, can you please advise how Can I do it.

Comment: If your variable length exceeds 4096 characters, you will get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zgw6.png)

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that this is not possible, there is a limit 4096:

> TFS.WebApi.Exception: Length of variable 'testVal2' is invalid. It must be between 0 and 4096 characters. If you cannot shorten it, please consider storing it in Azure key-vault, and linking it to a variable group as per this link. Another option is to keep it in secure files.

Answer (score 0):

Using [secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) to store the content, then read the content during build/release.